# C Pointers Output Not clear

Tags: c, pointers

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(void)
 {
   short x[12];
   unsigned char *cp;
   short *sp;
   int *ip;
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
     x[i] = i + 1;
   }
   cp = (unsigned char *) x;
   sp = (short *) x;
   ip = (int *) x;
   printf("1)*cp = %x\n",*cp);
   printf("A)*ip = %x\n",*ip);
   ip = ip + 2;
   printf("B)*ip = %x\n",*ip);
   cp[1]--;
   printf("C) cp[1] = %d\n", cp[1]);
   printf("D)*sp = %d\n",*sp);
   sp[3] = sp[3] + 257;
   printf("E) cp[6] = %x\n", cp[6]);
   printf("F) cp[7] = %x\n", cp[7]);
 return 0;
 }
```

This code produces the following output

```
 1)*cp = 1
 A)*ip = 20001
 B)*ip = 60005
 C) cp[1] = 255
 D)*sp = -255
 E) cp[6] = 5
 F) cp[7] = 1
```

Am sure about the logic behind this. Does unsigned char needs something do with the output. I am not getting why 20001 is outputted by integer pointer ip and how cp[6] is 5

Comment: [What is the strict aliasing rule and how to get around it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/995714)

Answer (score 1):

`*ip` causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/1505939) due to violating the strict aliasing rule. You may not use an lvalue of type `int` to access memory declared as `short`.

Since the behaviour is undefined, the entire output of the program is meaningless, so you should not worry about why any particular output happened.